# Combining Data Across Multiple Data Fields

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I am trying to create a common data field based on multiple columns below. When I try to use nvl i am getting blank values in the common field and its not getting picked up..The input and output tables are below:

**Input table**

| model-manufacture | model -CAM | MODEL -schedule |
| --- | --- | --- |
|  | CX190 |  |
|  | NM890 | NM890 |
| JK1231 |  |  |
| LO121 | LO121 |  |
|  |  | VB1231 |
| OPE12 |  | ope12 |
| jk7812 |  |  |

**Output table**

| model-common | model-manufacture | model -CAM | MODEL -schedule |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CX190 |  | CX190 |  |
| NM890 |  | NM890 | NM890 |
| JK1231 | JK1231 |  |  |
| LO121 | LO121 | LO121 |  |
| VB1231 |  |  | VB1231 |
| ope12 | OPE12 |  | ope12 |
| jk7812 | jk7812 |  |  |

**Query Used**

```
select nvl(model-manufacture,model-CAM,MODEL-schedule) as model-common
from input
```

Comment: Do the `model-manufacture`,`model-CAM`, and `MODEL-schedule` fields contain blank values (empty strings) or nulls? Empty strings are not null and nvl will return an empty string if that's the first non-null in the list of parameters.

Comment: @GregPavlik: They are empty strings ....Can you please suggest what should I do in this case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On wa is to replace empty strings with NULL with `nullif`

But it would be best, to save `NULL`

```
select nvl(nullif(TRIM(model-manufacture),'')
,nullif(TRIM(model-CAM),''),nullif(TRIM(MODEL-schedule),'')) as model-common
from input
```

Comment: Appreciate your response!...Even after using NULLIF i am getting blank values in model-common..

Comment: Is it possible those fields have nothing but whitespace in them? You can wrap the column names in nbk's answer with trim(). You can check using the length() function to see if they're non-zero length. If they are, they have whitespace and/or non-printable characters.

Comment: @user3369545 then you don't have empty strings, but as @GregPavlik suggested `TRIM` the coumns, before comparing